ES6 include references/dependencies in dynamic import
I have FileA that dynamically import FileB from different directory.
The dynamic import fail because FileB importing module 'lodash'.
The error show
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'lodash'.

FileA.js
// ... My other codes
import("file://D:/plugins/FileB.js");
// ... My other codes

FileB.js
import { now } from "lodash";
console.log(now());

export const Person = {
    name: "John Doe"
}

My question is how to add dependency that needed in dynamic import (here to add lodash in dynamic import)?
Note:

The codes is not for browser.
The FileA is npm project that have "lodash" installed as dependency. FileB is a single file located outside that project.
If I remove codes related to "lodash" in FileB the dynamic import
work fine.


"The code is not for browser." - then what is it for? Different environments have different module resolution algorithms. Read the documentation of the respective runtime.

its a CLI project. FileA will be installed globally

Again, what runtime are you using to run those scripts? Node, bun, deno, something else?

I run it with Node

When you dynamically import FileB from outside your project directory, Node.js doesn't recognize the project's node_modules folder as a source for dependencies for FileB. Here are some approaches you can try to make lodash accessible to FileB:
Option 1: Specify the Dependency Path with NODE_PATH
Set the NODE_PATH environment variable to point to the node_modules directory of your project. This allows Node.js to resolve modules from this path, even when importing files from outside the project.
For Windows, you can set NODE_PATH like this:
set NODE_PATH=D:\path\to\your\project\node_modules
node FileA.js

For macOS/Linux, use:
export NODE_PATH=/path/to/your/project/node_modules
node FileA.js

Option 2: Dynamically Load lodash in FileB
Modify FileB to load lodash dynamically within the function where it’s needed:
// FileB.js
const lodash = await import("lodash");
console.log(lodash.now());

export const Person = {
    name: "John Doe"
};

This approach allows you to specify lodash as a dependency in FileA's package.json, and FileB will use the dynamically imported lodash without breaking due to module resolution issues.
Option 3: Use an Absolute Path for FileB
Another workaround is to copy FileB into your project directory or use an absolute path to lodash:
// FileB.js
import { now } from "file:///D:/path/to/your/project/node_modules/lodash";
console.log(now());

export const Person = {
    name: "John Doe"
};

This way, lodash is explicitly loaded from your project’s node_modules.
Let me know if one of these methods helps, or if you have any specific constraints!

Why do you assume node.js?

Because FileA is an npm project?! The author has mentioned it explicitly...

Could be, but not every npm-published package is meant to be run in node.js.

Very thank you for the help with many options. Currently im checking for solution no 1 so I dont need to touch FileB. My problem now i have difficulty to set NODE_PATH programatically from FileA using EcmaScript. I know the directory to set. but i dont know how to set it via Javascript code
